# How can I remove all debug & personal info from an executable?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I have a C++ executable which was compiled with VS 2017. This executable still contains the Paths to .pdb files and so on used for debugging, which can be seen when the file is opened in notepad for example.

Now, for privacy reasons I want to remove those paths since they reveal my username.

I already tried to delete those by just opening the file in notepad and removing the Paths, but that made Windows recognize it as a 16-bit executable, causing it not to run properly.

So, is there a way to do this without breaking the executable?

Comment: Is this in the Release build?

Comment: Yup. It's set to release and not debug.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Thanks, that solved my problem.